# How to take two counts result from second table using MySQL JOIN

Tags: php, json, php-5.6

Here I have two tables, (`trip_details` & `trip_member`), my requirement is based on `tripId`. I want to get the employee present count and employee absent count. In the `trip_member` table I stored `tripId` (**foriegnkey**), `empId`, `empPresentStatus`. `empPresentStatus= '1'` means he is absent, `empPresentStatus ='0'` means is present.

> trip_details

```
tripId      allocationId       tripStatus

 1             1                  1
 2             1                  1
```

> trip_member

```
id       tripId          empId       empPresentStatus

 1         1              G2E201        0
 2         1              G2E202        0
 3         1              G2E203        1
 4         2              G2E204        0
 5         2              G2E205        1
```

based on my table structure, how many employee present in the trip and how many employee absent in the trip, I want to take the count.

> I tried this

```
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT a.tripId, a.cabNo, COUNT('b.*') AS absentCount FROM trip_details a LEFT JOIN trip_member b ON a.tripId = b.tripId WHERE b.empPresentStatus = '1' AND a.tripStatus ='1' GROUP BY a.tripId");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
} // my requirement is based on tripId I want take the employee present count and emplyee absent count, in trip_member table I stored tripId (forienkey),empId,empPresentStatus.here come to know like empPresentStatus= '1' means he is absent, suppose empPresentStatus ='0' means is present.
$arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'data' =>$data );
echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

> Output I am getting

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "cabNo": "CBX100",
        "absentCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "tripId": "2",
        "cabNo": "CBX101",
        "absentCount": "1"
    }
]
}
```

Up to now ok. I want to take the count how many employee are present in the trip. I don't how to take this count, if anyone know means update my answer.

> Expected Results

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "cabNo": "CBX100",
        "absentCount": "1",
        "presentCount": "2"
    },
    {
        "tripId": "2",
        "cabNo": "CBX101",
        "absentCount": "1",
        "presentCount": "1"
    }
]
}
```

> Updated table (cab_allocation)

```
allocationId     shiftTiming        routeId     cabId
  1                 1                  1        CBX100
  2                 1                  1        CBX101
```

Comment: Wasn't it be easy if you have another column as `empAbsentStatus` and will be easier to do it in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use sub query in this.**

```
Change your query with this one.

"SELECT a.tripId, a.cabNo, (select count(*) from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=a.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '1') as presentcount,(select count(*) from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=a.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '0') as absentcount FROM trip_details a WHERE a.tripStatus ='1' GROUP BY a.tripId"
```

Comment: I tried your code i am not getting my expected results, i am getting like this 
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "tripId": "1",
            "cabNo": "CBX100",
            "presentcount": "1",
            "absentcount": "2"
        },
        {
            "tripId": "2",
            "cabNo": "CBX101",
            "presentcount": "1",
            "absentcount": "1"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Trip id 1, it should come like this  "absentCount": "1", and  "presentCount": "2", but your query return wrong

Comment: Just change condition in sub query.

"SELECT a.tripId, a.cabNo, (select count(*) from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=a.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '1') as absentcount,(select count(*) from trip_member as m WHERE m.tripId=a.tripId and m.empPresentStatus = '0') as presentcount FROM trip_details a WHERE a.tripStatus ='1' GROUP BY a.tripId"

Comment: I tried I am getting {"status":"success","data":null}

Comment: did you use above query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152591/discussion-between-priyank-and-kanniyappan-r).